# 'hide axis' ignores 'ymax'

Tags: pgfplots

In the MWE below, when my axis has the `hide axis` property, then `ymin` and `ymax` properties are completely ignored. I know I can add a manual `\vskip`, but this plot is part of a beamer presentation which shows plots one by one and I want to fix the axis limits of the figure so that all plots have the same dimensions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[scale=1.5, mark=none, xmin=-1,xmax=1,
        ymin=-1, ymax=1, samples=100, 
        hide axis % Comment this to lower the text below 
        ]
        \plot[domain=-1:1] {x^2};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}


    This should be much lower
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known "problem" which first raised with PGFPlots v1.8. (Most of the people want the "new" behavior, so it is considered a *feature*.) You can "undo" this by adding `compat/BB=1.7` to the `axis` options to avoid it for this particular plot or to the global `\pgfplotsset` options if you want to avoid it for all of your plots.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % the "problem" occurs for `compat=1.8' or higher
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        compat/BB=1.7,      % <-- added
        scale=1.5,
        xmin=-1,    xmax=1,
        ymin=-1,    ymax=1,
        samples=101,
        hide axis,          % Comment this to lower the text below
        mark=none,
    ]
        \addplot [domain=-1:1] {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

    This should be much lower
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks! Add me to the list of people who do not want this new "feature".